# Show the workflow tasks below the list item the workflow belongs to

Tags: workflow, tasks

I would like to see the workflow tasks related to a list item directly under the items itself.
Is this possible (without using the sharepoint designer).
We are using Sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 1):

without SPD, this will not be possible.

However, you can try to :

1. create a custom view to the task list
2. apply filters on the content type to show only WF related tasks
3. group by "target item" (not sure of the English term)

This will show in a tree view fashion, the items and their tasks below. However, you won't be able to see neither item with no task nor item's details.

Is there any reason not to use SPD ?

Comment: Thanks, this helps as work around. Our IT department prefers not to use the designer, only after a business case supports getting a sharepoint devloper in.

Comment: @Bart: The designer is actually very easy to use. At least compared to the Excel documents I've seen the accountants create. I'd at least give it a shot.